# Is matplotlib slower in Python3?

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.6

I recently switched from 2.7 to 3.6. I'm doing 3D plots with pyplot and
it's much slower than before, particularly when dragging to change the viewpoint, even for very simple plots. Is this a common problem?

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
x = [0.,1.,1.]
y = [0.,0.,1.]
z = [0.,1.,0.]
verts = [list(zip(x,y,z))]

ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts))
plt.show()
```

Comment: There are too many things that can determine the plotting speed. Can you be sure that you used the exact same script with the same backend? If so, it would be good to post this example here, for others to test.

Comment: I added a simple example

Comment: So both environments do use the same backend? (i'm not a big 3d-plot user so i don't know much about the performance-effects but there should be many possible choices like tk, qt4, qt5, ...)

Comment: This draws 3 points. Panning this 3-point plot is really fast. How did you measure the speed?

Comment: It isn't fast at all in my case

Comment: I'm running macOS Sierra 10.12.3

Comment: OK, I fixed it. I was using MacOSX as backend. Switched to Qt5 and everything works much better.

Answer (score 2):

The speed improved from abysmal to quite fast after:

```
import matplotlib
print(matplotlib.get_backend())  # MacOSX
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')  # the backend must be changed before
                          # importing pyplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```